# Primes formed by concatenating the mersenne numbers from $2^2-1$ to $2^n-1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, mersenne-numbers

Concatenate the mersenne numbers $2^2-1$ to $2^n-1$ and define $f(n)$ to be the emerging number , for example $$f(6)=\color\red {3}\color\green {7}\color\red {15}\color\green {31}\color\red {63}$$

We get a prime number for $n=2,3,6,10,23$ and no other such prime numbers with less than $10\ 000$ digits exist.

> - Can we expect infinite many such primes ?
> - What is the next number $n$ such that $f(n)$ is prime ?

The following table shows the numbers $n$ upto $n=1\ 000$ , such that $f(n)$ has no prime divisor less than or equal to $611\ 953$ , the $50\ 000$ th prime. The second column shows the number of digits of $f(n)$

```
? t=prod(j=1,50*10^3,prime(j));k=2;s=2^k-1;k=k+1;s=c(s,2^k-1);while(k<1000,k=k+1
;s=c(s,2^k-1);if(gcd(s,t)==1,print(k,"  ",length(digits(s)))))
6  8
10  21
18  60
22  87
23  94
45  334
47  363
66  698
99  1538
102  1631
118  2172
150  3484
161  4006
165  4205
183  5159
202  6272
215  7097
221  7495
238  8681
239  8753
258  10187
267  10904
273  11395
282  12152
293  13111
310  14666
317  15331
334  17008
339  17518
341  17724
370  20846
406  25074
425  27463
426  27592
435  28764
453  31182
471  33696
477  34556
497  37501
498  37651
501  38104
509  39326
510  39480
514  40099
526  41986
534  43267
543  44732
551  46054
555  46723
573  49790
575  50137
579  50834
581  51184
582  51360
591  52955
609  56219
615  57328
695  73154
717  77844
723  79149
729  80464
738  82457
742  83351
743  83575
749  84926
767  89044
783  92787
803  97575
846  108276
867  113703
875  115806
891  120070
911  125508
917  127163
934  131910
935  132192
939  133323
946  135313
959  139049
966  141081
?
```

Comment: My impression is that questions about primes, like "are there finitely many primes of some specific kind" are usually either elementary of the kind the ancient Greeks or a math-interested fourteen-year old would understand a proof, or difficult in the level of "We have no idea how to even approach this". I suspect your question is if the last type, especially because it's base sensitive.

Comment: @Arthur What about Maynard's 2016 proof that there are infinitely many primes without any single digit in their decimal expansion? That is highly interesting.

Comment: @ParcyTaxel I said "usually". There are, of course, exceptions, even to my "base dependence makes things difficult" statement (for instance, I seem to recall the number of primes of the form $311\cdots11$ wasn't too hard to prove, although I have to admit I don't even remember the result right now). I still stand by what I said.

Comment: @Arthur Do you want to say that it is known whether finite or infinite many numbers of the form $311\cdots 11$ are prime ? That would be truely sensational.

Comment: $f(22)$ splits into the $36$-digit prime $507474152257665335620852313693486731$ and the $51$-digit prime $732119320008072727847653027077224717362320839422813$

Comment: If we define $g(n)$ as concatenating in reverse, for example $g(6)=\color\red {63}\color\green {31}\color\red {15}\color\green {7}\color\red {3}$ , then $g(n)$ is prime for $n=2,3$ and no other $n\le 300$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Parcly, could you please provide a reference to the Maynard paper?

Comment: @Klangen [Primes with restricted digits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.01041).

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thank you. On Arxiv it does not say in which journal this was published. Was it ever published (the paper is from 2016)?

Comment: @Klangen In mathematics, publishing on arXiv is publishing.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I thought it was for pre-prints and that papers hosted there are eventually submitted to a relevant journal.

Comment: @Klangen You are right. Eventually, important result should be published, but it may take a while for several reasons. In this case, the result is appearing as _Maynard, J.: Invent. math. (2019) 217: 127. [https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-019-00865-6](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-019-00865-6)_.

Comment: Well, we can eliminate any input $n$ if $n\equiv 1,2\pmod 6$ as they produce digit sums that are $0 \bmod 3$ . Any input, $n\equiv 0\bmod 4$ still returns a number ending in $5$ .  Those two combine to eliminate $n\equiv 0,1,2,4,7,8 \pmod 12$